# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid TypeError not a supported Ruby type, with NuoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, nuodb

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 with a legacy NuoDB database and the activerecord-nuodb-adapter gem. The database is connected and I can get an accurate list of tables with ActiveRecord::Base.connections.tables.

Here's the error:

```
[2] pry(main)> Store.first
  Store Load (3.2ms)  SELECT `store`.* FROM `store` FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TypeError: not a supported ruby type: 2004: SELECT `store`.* FROM `store`  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
from /home/bion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-nuodb-adapter-1.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/nuodb_adapter.rb:905:in `columns'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type error has been resolved in an update of the nuodb ruby driver.

Answer (score 0):

What version of NuoDB are you using?

I believe that you have also posted to the NuoDB forums and followed up with the conclusion that this is being caused by the NuoBN binary datatype not being coerced into a supported Ruby datatype. Is that correct?